# How To Create Infinite Category children in one SQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I need method in  Php and mysql for   Creating Infinite Category children in one SQL table , like this

```
 Main Category   >  sub Category > sub Category > sub Category ... etc
```

so any Category can have sub Category  and each one can have sub Category

i hope my question is understandable

Comment: kind of the best source on the topic i have ever read, and refer back to: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: this need more tables i need just one table

Comment: why only one? why make things harder for yourself? why write bad code when you can write good code?

Comment: i have limited tables to use and this code is easier , because all categories have the same property , so just adding parent key will solve the problem , keep in maind the admin will change the order later and that will help  more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this method :
in one table you can declare the parent for each Category by id , then you can find the sub Categories for each one
and when you get one category first check if has any parent 
like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyCategories where `parent`='0'
```

then you need to fetch this using php and then find the sub Categories
something like this:

```
// do your fetch
$id = $row['id'];
```

then get sub Categories

```
SELECT * FROM MyCategories where `parent`='$id'
```

i hope it will help you

Comment: and one more thing make sure that you set the parent 0 if the new category is the main category